# Is ReadDirectoryChanges blocking write access?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I have an app that tracks changes in a directory and uploads them to a server.

```
auto hdir = CreateFile(dir.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
for (;;)
{
    vector<char> d(16384);
    DWORD by = 0;
    ReadDirectoryChangesW(hdir, d.data(), 16384, false, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, &by, 0, 0); 
    ... // Process changes and upload them
}
```

However it seems that ReadDirectoryChanges blocks some write access. When Visual Studio starts a project within a tracked directory, it complains that Admin access is needed for that directory (but there is no attempt to write anything, ReadDirectoryChanges() does not return from my app).

When a file is updated, the function correctly returns and I'm processing it, however I 've noticed that some times Visual Studio creates a temporary file inside the directory, probably a recover file.

What's wrong with this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the directory, you are sharing only read access, not write access. Add the `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` flag:

```
auto hdir = CreateFile(..., FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, ...);
```

Also, you are not checking for errors at all.

```
auto hdir = CreateFile(...);
if (hdir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    // handle error...
}
else {
    for (;;) {
        ...
        if (!ReadDirectoryChangesW(...)) {
            // handle error...
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    CloseHandle(hdir);
}
```